# Show UISearchDisplayController's searchResultsTableView when empty text on ios7

Tags: ios7, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a non-UITableViewController with searchBar and UISearchDisplayController, ios 7 targeted.
When the searchBar is selected it animates to the top of screen and everything else is dimmed.

I used the next code to show the searchResultsTableView when the **searchBar is still empty**:

```
    - (void)searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
    {
         [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView setHidden:FALSE];
    }
```

Now the ResultsTableView **is displayed**, with the right data ,but it **is dimmed** like everything else and the **cells cant be selected**. When trying to select a cell, the searchDisplayController dismisses.

How can i make it un-dimmed and selectable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not getting your problem but as i think you need to remove dimmed view and if i understand correct then below code will help you

```
-(void) searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{
    for(UIView * v in myDocSearchDisplayController.searchContentsController.view.subviews)
    {
        if([v isMemberOfClass:[UIControl class]] || ([[[v class] description] isEqualToString:@"UISearchDisplayControllerContainerView"]))
        {
            [v removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
}
```